# Django / file uploads permissions

Tags: django, file-upload, permissions, django-uploads

I wrote a django app, but I have a little problem with the file permissions of the uploads files from a web form.

Basically I can upload a .mp3 file but it always keep chmod 600.

The container folder has chmod 775, and the umask is set to 022.

I'm in a shared hosting service.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try this in your settings.py if you use Python 2:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0644
```

In Python 3 octal numbers must start with 0o so the line would be:

```
FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644
```

For more details [see the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS).

Comment: In case someone needs the link to the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS

Comment: [Numbers starting with 0 are base 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python). The prefix [`0o`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11620194/1888983) is an alternative, that the docs mention.

Comment: In python 3 octal numbers must start with `0o` so the line would be: `FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS = 0o644`

Comment: when I try to print my setting.UPLOAD_FILE_PERMISSIONS, it is null?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is useful. The below method can be used. This has 2 other advantages other than resolving permission errors.

- No issues with file permissions
- More faster
- The file is not copied to /tmp/ folder for files which are more than 2.5 MB (saving space as well).

---

```
with open(file_name, 'wb+') as temp_file:
    for chunk in up_file.chunks():
        temp_file.write(chunk)
```