# creating folders with correct permissions django uploads

Tags: python, django, permissions, directory

When uploading files, I am setting the `upload_to` to a function that creates a path doesn't exist, and Django is creating the extra folders (with permissions I don't like).

For example,

```
def photo_upload_path(instance, filename):  
    return os.path.join('photos', str(instance.id), filename)
```

however, the permissions of the folder are not what I would like. Should I create the folder and set the permissions? Or is there a setting for this?

I found a post for controlling permissions of uploaded files ([django / file uploads permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608579/django-file-uploads-permissions)), but not created directories.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

You could change the default directory permission in your settings file.  This is available after Django 1.7, and is fully described in [the Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#file-upload-directory-permissions).  Note that this will affect all directories created by Django, including staticfiles, so use with caution.

```py
FILE_UPLOAD_DIRECTORY_PERMISSIONS = 0o755
```

Change the example code to use the permission you desire.  I didn't use your requested permission (0o777) in my example code in case someone copies without reading.

Answer (score 0):

so I ended up finding out a solution for the permissions.

I was using apache, so I believe it was actually not 100% a django issue.

If I edit `/etc/apache2/envvars` and set add a line such as `umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rwx`, it sets the default permissions