# Python cannot handle numbers string starting with 0. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

I just executed the following program on my python interpreter:

```
>>> def mylife(x):
...     if x>0:
...             print(x)
...     else:
...             print(-x)
... 
>>> mylife(01)
File "<stdin>", line 1
mylife(01)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> mylife(1)
1
>>> mylife(-1)
1
>>> mylife(0)
0
```

Now, I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python) but as the link says, the 0 for octal does not work any more in python (i.e. does not work in python3). But does that not mean that the the behaviour for numbers starting with 0 should be interpreted properly? Either in base-2 or in normal base-10 representation? Since it is not so, why does python behave like that? Is it an implementation issue? Or is it a semantic issue?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

My guess is that since `012` is no longer an octal literal constant in python3.x, they disallowed the `012` syntax to avoid strange backward compatibility bugs.  Consider your python2.x script which using octal literal constants:

```
a = 012 + 013
```

Then you port it to python 3 and it still works -- It just gives you `a = 25` instead of `a = 21` as you expected previously (decimal).  Have fun tracking down that bug.

Comment: Yup. Seems like a good explanation, as possible design decision. May be after two years, when most of the stuff has been ported, then, I think, the feature should be allowed again. Thanks!

Comment: Reminds of the "Why do programmers confuse Christmas and Halloween" - "Because dec(25) is oct(31)" ;P

Comment: @JonClements -- I'd never seen that one before -- Quite clever -- I suppose that was probably mentioned in one of the CS classes I never took.

Comment: @mgilson probably the good reason. Which explains why `000` is still valid: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071916/why-does-000-evaluate-to-0-in-python-3

Comment: @mgilson with '0' it works , with '00' or '000' it fails giving that "invalid token" errro

Comment: Octal was the first suspect for me too. However, in the code it's a str and quotes. In the DB it's quoted as well, where the  numeric content can arise from? Also: the error is coming  from psycopg2: `psycopg2.errors.InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type json\\nLINE 3: ...d_on) = 2 AND (app_cache.some_field -> 2) IN (\\'00\\'...` . I have no control of what castings psycopg2 might possibly do inside...

Comment: @SwissNavy -- yours is getting rejected by psycopg2 -- not python.  Something interesting is happening when you are formatting that SQL query.  That seems like a different root problem compared to _this_ question.

Answer (score 15):

From the Python 3 release notes http://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#integers

> Octal literals are no longer of the form `0720`; use `0o720` instead.

The 'leading zero' syntax for octal literals in Python 2.x was a common gotcha:

```
Python 2.7.3
>>> 010
8
```

In Python 3.x it's a syntax error, as you've discovered:

```
Python 3.3.0
>>> 010
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    010
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

You can still convert from strings with leading zeros same as ever:

```
>>> int("010")
10
```