# Python : Right Shift >> 26

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary

```
0010 1101 1011 0100 0111 1100 1000 0101
```

i would like to right shift 26,but failed

```
print(bin(00101101101101000111110010000101) >> 26)
```

and the debug error is SyntaxError: invalid token

right shift 26 should be return 1011

how about this?

```
0010 1101 1011 0100 0111 1100 1000 0101
```

Shift 0010 1101 1011 0100 0111 1100 1000 0101>>22 returns 10110110 
And with 00001111 returns 0110 converts to decimal 6 ?

with 00001111?how to do this with 00001111?

Comment: try `int('00101101101101000111110010000101',2) >> 26`

Comment: `print(bin(0b00101101101101000111110010000101 >> 26))`

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013638/python-cannot-handle-numbers-string-starting-with-0-why/13013678#13013678

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your use of `bin()` is wrong. [The documentation states](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin):

> Convert an integer number to a binary string.

Since that is not what you're after, that is wrong. You're trying to right-shift a string, which isn't possible.

You mean:

```
print(0b00101101101101000111110010000101 >> 26)
```

or, if you want the answer as a binary string:

```
print(bin(0b00101101101101000111110010000101 >> 26))
```

Here, the prefix `0b` is used in Python for a binary number literal.

Answer (score 2):

`bin` returns a string which is the string's binary representation.

```
print (0b00101101101101000111110010000101 >> 26)
```

should work I think.

The syntax error that you're seeing is because an integer literal can't start with `0` in python3.x -- In python2.x, that meant that you wanted to declare an octal literal.

e.g. (python2.x):

```
>>> print 025
21
```

Answer (score 1):

- Prefix your binary number with `0b` to indicate to Python it is a binary number.
- First shift right, then convert it to binary.

Try this:

```
print(bin(0b00101101101101000111110010000101 >> 26))
```

Edit: outputs:

```
0b1011
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation for [Python bin()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bin), it looks like you should be passing bin() a decimal integer, so it's interpreting 00101101101101000111110010000101 as decimal.

Comment: Well, as you noted above, that's a Python 2 vs 3 issue, right? :)

Comment: Sort of -- But 001... isn't interpreted as a *decimal* in any version of python.  In python2.x it's interpreted as *octal*, in python3.x, it's a syntax error. -- Maybe you meant to say that it's **NOT** interpreting 001011011... as decimal?