# Storing integer with leading zero in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why does Python behave strangely when I store integers with leading zeros into a variable? One gives an error while the other one stores the value wrongly?

```
>>> zipcode = 02492
SyntaxError: invalid token

>>> zipcode = 02132
>>> zipcode
1114
```

Comment: How is this question off topic and why the downvote?

Comment: Why use an integer? A ZIP code is not a numeric quantity.

Comment: a) Integers don't *have* leading zeroes. b) Zip codes aren't integers.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13013638/748858

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numbers beginning with a 0 are interpreted as [octal numbers](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-octinteger).

```
In [32]: oct(1114)
Out[32]: '02132'

In [33]: int('2132', 8)
Out[33]: 1114

In [34]: 02132 == 1114
Out[34]: True
```

Note that [in Python3](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/), octal literals must be specified with a leading `0o` or `0O`, instead of `0`.

Answer (score 3):

`int` literals with leading zero are interpreted as octal, in which `9` is not a valid number. Only numbers formed with digits in range `[0, 7]` are valid octal numbers.