# Why does 000 evaluate to 0 in Python 3?

Tags: python, int, literals

Since the octal prefix is now `0o` in Python 3 it's not legal to write `0777` any more. Okay.

So why is it legal to write `00` which evaluates properly to `0` whereas other digits trigger a syntax error?

```
>>> 01
  ...
  File "<interactive input>", line 1
    01
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> 
>>> 00
0
```

Comment: Looks like a `decinteger`: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals (didnt dv)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, looks very much like that. But what's the use for it?

Comment: based on the syntax I would say only a sequence of zeros is allowed (if it does not start with a non-zero digit or with a `0o`, `0b`, etc.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If one takes a look at the [*Lexical Analysis*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals) (Integer Literal Section) page:

> ```
> integer      ::=  decinteger | bininteger | octinteger | hexinteger
> decinteger   ::=  nonzerodigit (["_"] digit)* | "0"+(["_"] "0")*
> ...
> ```

So that means that a `decinteger` either begins with a nonzero digit (followed by all possible digits and optionally underscores), or is a **sequence of zeros** with optionally underscores (which maps to zero).

The documentation furthermore states that:

> Note that leading zeros in a **non-zero decimal number** are **not** allowed.

So it means they make an exception for zero (in all documentation for [python-3.3](/questions/tagged/python-3.3) one can find there): you can write zero as a sequence of zeros. My guess is that of course they have to include `"0"` (how else would you specify zero as a `decinteger`?), so why not allow more zeros in that case, regardless of the number system, `000` is and stays zero. They probably do not want to allow `01` as a `decinteger` to prevent accidentally running [python-2.x](/questions/tagged/python-2.x) code and thus obtaining totally different results.

Finally note that the **underscores are only part of that specification since [python-3.6](/questions/tagged/python-3.6)**: in the [specifications for 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals) they are not mentioned in the grammar.

In [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7) [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-literals) specifies a zero followed by other digits (also other zeros as an `octinteger`:

> ```
> integer        ::=  decimalinteger | octinteger | hexinteger | bininteger
> decimalinteger ::=  nonzerodigit digit* | "0"
> octinteger     ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") octdigit+ | "0" octdigit+
> ```

Comment: that's part of the answer, thanks. But anyone knows what's the use? and `00_00` is still invalid syntax BTW.

Comment: `00_00` works fine with my Python 3.6

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: my guess would be that a sequence of zeros is always zero, regardless of the radix one uses.

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski ok so the underscores are new, since in 3.4 it doesn't work.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem. I wanted more than a guess, but thanks anyway :) BTW you could add that the underscore syntax is new since 3.5 or 3.6 since it doesn't work on 3.4

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: if one looks at multiple versions of the documentation, it starts at 3.6.

Comment: Please someone could tell me what is the meaning of "+" and "*" in the notation `"0"+(["_"] "0")* `

Comment: @AngelSalazar: this is a variant of the *Backus-Naur form*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus_Naur_form