# python not accepting 09 but accepts 07

Tags: python-2.7

Does anyone why python handles the below this way.

```
>>> a = 099
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = 099
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> a = 088
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = 088
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> a = 0559
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = 0559
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> a = 077
>>>
```

It does not seem to accept numbers starting with 0 and preceding with 8 or 9. If it is some other number, it is not throwing any error. Why is that?

Comment: `099` is interpreted as octal number, but 9 is not valid octal digit

Comment: also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071916/why-does-000-evaluate-to-0-in-python-3

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2, like in C, an integer literal that starts with a `0` is in *octal*. Digits 8 and 9 do not exist in octal (they are written `010` and `011` respectively) so that is a syntax error.

```
>>> 010
8
>>> 08
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    008
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

In Python 3, this feature not many people know about is gone. There, nonzero literals that start with a `0` are syntax errors.

Comment: not _all_ literals: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071916/why-does-000-evaluate-to-0-in-python-3