# what is the difference between "eval" and "int"

Tags: python, python-3.x

Earlier I heard that `eval(input(a))` will convert a string automatically to int, but if i code

```
age = eval(input("enter age"))
```

during input i type in 01 it is an error, but when i code

```
age = int(input("enter age"))
```

01 as input works perfectly. Why is it?

Comment: If you use `eval` you could end up with something disastrous like `eval("__import__('os').system('rm -rf $HOME')")` (which would delete files in your home directory, DON'T actually try this...)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`eval` evaluates the python expression. In python 3, numbers starting by `0` aren't allowed (except for `0000`, see [Why does 000 evaluate to 0 in Python 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43071916/why-does-000-evaluate-to-0-in-python-3)). In python 2, those are interpreted as octal (base 8) numbers. Not better... (python 3 base 8 now uses exclusively `Oo` prefix)

`int` performs a string to integer conversion, so it cannot evaluate a complex expression (that you don't need), but isn't subjected to this leading zero syntax.

Another nice feature is that you can check if the entered expression is an integer by using a simple and qualified `try/except` block:

```
while True:
   try:
       age = int(input("enter age"))
       break
   except ValueError:
       print("Retry!")
```

(with `eval` you would have to protect against all exceptions)

Advice: use `int`, because it's safer, doesn't have security issues (eval can evaluate *any* expression, including system calls and file deletion), and suits your purpose perfectly.

Note: the above code is still unsafe with python 2: `input` acts like `eval`. You could protect your code against this with the simple code at the start of your module:

```
try:
    input = raw_input
except NameError:
    pass
```

so python 2 `input` is not unreachable anymore and calls `raw_input` instead. Python 3 ignores that code.

Comment: Not only is it safer - it'll also fail so you can re-try or whatever if an `int` can't be produced - rather than produce *something* that isn't one...

Comment: Can i understand it as `eval` is use to perform much complex expression while `int` only convert a string to integer? What are octal and zero syntax?

Comment: eval evaluates any python code. int tries to convert any type to integer (float, bool, string ...). you got it. Octal is base 8 representation: in python 2: `010 == 8` (like binary or hex). In python 3 that doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 6):

`eval()` is used to verify an expression. On number is considered an expression, except octal numbers (numbers that start with 0). `int()` handles string to integer conversion. There are many reasons why you should avoid using `eval()`. Just keep in mind:

- Python 2.x

  ```py
  x = raw_input('Enter number here: ')
  ```
- Python 3.x

  ```py
  x = input('Enter number here: ')
  ```
- Python 2.x
  Security risk:

  ```py
  x = input('Enter number here: ')
  ```
- Python 3.x
  Security risk:

  ```py
  x = eval(input('Enter number here: '))
  ```

Also, keep in mind that `eval()` has the potential to run code, which could cause a huge security risk. I suggest not using it unless you clearly know what you're doing or it could compromise your application.

Comment: What kind of security risk? i'm new to programming

Comment: You can check out many different examples and explanations [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html)

Comment: you can for example `import subprocess; eval("subprocess.run('whatever program I like')")` that is very dangerous and the user should not probably be allowed to do it. Hence, you should pass only 100% trustworthy input to `eval`.