# How to generate wordlist contain time-stamps?

Tags: python

I'm performing some CTF challenge online and I need to generate time-stamps for bruteforcing.

What I want to know is how to generate time stamps in hh:mm format and with all numbers possible, for example 00:00 - 00:01 ... 12:23 and so on.

I wrote this code from someone but I don't get it much:

```
for h in range(24):
print(f"{h:02d}")
```

Output:

```
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
```

Comment: It looks like you're well on your way with the hours. How might you apply this same logic for minutes?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't install pandas library then use two iteration:

```
for h in range(24):
    for m in range(60):
        print(f"{h:02d}" + ":" + f"{m:02d}")
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

The minute should increase by 1. You can use fix base `datetime` object and add a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) of 1 minute for this:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

base_time = datetime.strptime('2022-07-03 00:00', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
minute = timedelta(minute=1)
t1 = base_time + minute
print(t1)

# use a loop or list-comprehension to iteratively add minute to form a sequence
```

#### See also

- [Generate interval based timestamps in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45158581/generate-interval-based-timestamps-in-python)
- GeeksforGeeks: [Pandas - Generating ranges of timestamps using Python](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pandas-generating-ranges-of-timestamps-using-python/)