# Why does it show error while inputting numbers with leading 0s in python ( not sure if this is same with other languages too)?

Tags: python, variables, int, leading-zero

So I was working on a python program and by mistake added a 0 in the number while inputting it, as
`n = 01`
It showed the following error:-
`File "<ipython-input-50-2724200336d1>", line 1`
`n = 01`
`^`
`SyntaxError: invalid token`

Why does this happen?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13013638/python-cannot-handle-numbers-string-starting-with-0-why

Comment: This isn't a "trailing 0". Trailing implies the 0 as at the end whereas in your case it is at the start.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused in there. And yeap, that works, thanks for the help :)