# Python 2.7 str(055) returns "45" instead of 055

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Why I get the following result in python 2.7, instead of '055'?

```
>>> str(055)
'45'
```

Comment: just entering `055` without the `str` returns `45` as well, fyi

Comment: [What do numbers starting with 0 mean in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python)

Comment: Note that `str(1 2 3)` is a syntax error, and `str(asdf)` won't produce `'asdf'` unless `asdf` is a variable containing `'asdf'`. The argument to `str` is evaluated as an ordinary Python expression; it's not like putting quotation marks around something.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`055` is an octal number whose decimal equivalent is `45`, use `oct` to get the correct output.

```
>>> oct(055)
'055'
```

[Syntax for octal numbers](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#integer-and-long-integer-literals) in Python 2.X:

```
octinteger     ::=  "0" ("o" | "O") octdigit+ | "0" octdigit+
```

But this is just for representation purpose, ultimately they are always converted to integers for either storing or calculation:

```
>>> x = 055
>>> x
45
>>> x = 0xff   # HexaDecimal
>>> x
255
>>> x = 0b111  # Binary
>>> x
7
>>> 0xff * 055
11475
```

**Note** that in Python 3.x octal numbers are now represented by `0o`. So, using `055` there will raise `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Note also that in Python3.x decimal numbers with leading zeros aren't allowed, they're a syntax error.

Comment: Thank god for the Python3 change. It's far too easy to accidentally read a number as octal

Comment: thanks a lot. that clears my confusion!