# Binary in Python

Tags: python, binary

When I write run the following code in Python:

```
m = 010001110110100101110110011001010010000001101101011001010010000001100001011011100010000001000001

print "m = ", m
```

I receive the output:

m =  7772840013437408857694157721741838884340237826753178459792706472536593002623651807233

What's happening?  Is Python automatically converting from base 2 to base 10?

Comment: ^There's your answer. I'll add that I partly diagnosed it by playing around in the interpreter. Just a tip. And, for binary: `m = 0b111` yields 7, for example.

Answer (score 2):

You're starting `m` with `0`. Python assumes it's an Octal (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python))

What you're seeing is the decimal representation of the octal number.

If you want to work with that as binary numbers, I'd recommend setting it as an `str` and then parse it to `int` specifying that you're parsing something in base 2:

```
>>> m='0100011'
>>> int(m, 2)
35
```

Answer (score 0):

Kind of, it interprets a number starting with 0 as octal, so it actually isn't binary in the first place.

In any case, you can make it output the integer as binary like so:

```
print "m = ", "{0:b}".format(m)
```