# datetime in python ridiculous error

Tags: python, datetime

When I type

```
datetime.date(2104,06,08)
```

or

```
datetime.date(2014,06,09)
```

I get an error

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
 datetime.date(2014,06,08)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

But when I remove the zero in '08' or '09' it works. The problem seems to be only with 8 and 9 and not with any other numbers. If anyone knows a work around, it would be great

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-specify-hexadecimal-and-octal-integers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A number literal starting with 0 is interpreted as octal (base 8). 8 and 9 aren't octal digits.

Just don't use leading zeros.

Answer (score 1):

This is because **a leading zero** is **octal notation**.

But in octal notation there do not exist such expressions as 08 or 09.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `0` in front of a number makes it base `8`, there are no `08` or `09` in base `8` only (well, not only, but for single digits):

```
00
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
```

Avoid using the zero out in front and you should be ok.