# Error when get value from list with index as 08 or 09

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know the format for calling a value from list is a[0] or a[1]. 
When I tried for getting values as a[01] or a[06] and still got the answers. 
But when getting value for a[08] or a[09], it throws syntax error.
Any idea why it is so?

```
>>> a = [1,2,6,8,9,22,3,44,5,67,11]
>>> a[05]
22
>>> a[09]
   File "<stdin>", line 1
   a[09]
      ^
   SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> a[08]
  File "<stdin>", line 1
  a[08]
     ^
 SyntaxError: invalid token
>>> a[07]
44
>>> a[8]
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When starting a number with 0, it is assumed to be octal. So it is invalid when 8 or 9 is encountered here.

Have a look at the following answers:

- [Why is 08 or 09 in Python invalid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423960/why-is-08-or-09-in-python-invalid?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [What do numbers starting with 0 mean in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python)
- [Python: Invalid Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336181/python-invalid-token)