# Which token is invalid in this arrow call?

Tags: python

The following code fails

```
In [1]: import arrow

In [2]: arrow.get(2015, 06, 08, 23, 59)
  File "<ipython-input-2-44d7fca57336>", line 1
    arrow.get(2015, 06, 08, 23, 59)
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Why does this initialization [per the arrow docs](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/#creation) returns an error?

Comment: Putting a zero in front of a number makes it octal. `08` is not a valid octal number.

Comment: Ahhhhh, you are right! If you do not mind making this an answer I would accept it (and leave the question, as it is not that dumb after all)

Comment: Simplify your question down to where the error is. Try to reproduce it with as little code as possible. At the moment it's not a quality question.

Comment: @PeterWood: OK, done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a zero in front of a literal number makes it octal. See [What do numbers starting with 0 mean in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python).

Octal numbers can only contain the digits `0` to `7`.

`08` is not a valid octal number.

This has nothing to do with [arrow](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/#creation). The example you link doesn't use octal numbers.