# Large integers addition error in python 2.7.10

Tags: python, python-2.7, addition, largenumber

I am trying to solve a problem using python. In which I have to deal with large integers (upto 500 digits). According to my current stage of understanding, python can handle any numbers in same traditional way. But I have problem in simple addition like this:

```
>>> p= 1001101111101011011100101100100110111011111011000100111100111110111101011011011100111001100011111010
>>> q= 0011111011111010111101111110101101111001111111100011111101101100100011010011111011111110110011111000
>>> p+q
1001101111105557844987142979708366943425581971579987152809865568761000527613931421735161949470823522L
```

Can anyone please explain why i got such an error.

Comment: The result should just have 0s, 1s, and 2s.

Comment: [I've closed this as a duplicate of a question explaining what the 0 prefix means; if instead you're puzzled by something else, please edit to clarify and we can reopen.]

Comment: @DSM and as you probably already know, in Python 3 a leading zero is a syntax error so nobody gets surprised by this again. It's too bad that this conflicts with the intuitive understanding that leading zeros aren't significant.

Comment: P.S. it has nothing to do with large integers, you can see the problem with `100+010`.

Comment: No [DSM](http://stackoverflow.com/users/487339/dsm) I am pretty clear now. I am new in python as well as in Stack Exchange. So, that's my fault. I am sorry.

Comment: @[Mark Ransom](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom), No Sir, I don't use python 3. I didn't know the solution, I didn't know that the problem is due to the zero in the beginning, so, I thought this problem was somehow related to large Integers. Anyway, thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Var q starts with a zero, making it an octal number, rather than decimal

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python

Comment: Exactly, read that answer OP