# Dividing an Integer by Its Reverse in Python 3

Tags: python, integer, reverse, division

I am writing a program to to check if the quotient yielded by the division is a whole number or not.

The **dividend** (numerator if division) is the **given input integer**.
The **divisor** (Denominator) is the **reverse of the dividend**.

I implemented reversion for `90`, for example,by the following code:

```
>>> str(90)[::-1]
```

It yielded the following result:

```
>>> str(90)[::-1]
09
```

Now if i perform division between 90 (input) and 09 (reverse), it yields an error:

```
>>> 90/09
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

What should be done to eradicate this error and get the correct answer `10.0`?

**How to ignore that zero** if it is in the starting of either divisor or dividend?

Comment: Like `float('09')`?

Comment: You could use modulus function as thus returns the remainder of a division and test if  equal to zero. E.g. If x % y == 0

Comment: By the way, `09` is not a decimal number. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing is that you are trying to interactively calculate this and you are literally typing `09` in the interpreter. Numbers starting with 0 are interpreted as octal numbers (cf. [What do numbers starting with 0 mean in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python)) and 09 is an invalid octal representation.

The other thing is that the division will not work at all if you do not convert your string back to int or float, so it should be something like this:

```
num = 90
res = 90 / float(str(90)[::-1])
print(res)
```