# Double-digit int to string and startswith()

Tags: python, python-2.7

So, I have double-digit numbers below 100. Below 10 `python` doesn't handle them out-of-the-box. I have seen many different solutions, but I'm just fine with converting them to `strings` and then check whether the it starts with `0`.

The below code is just a sample test of checking the above condition, but fails:

```
num = 01
if str(num).startswith('0'):
    print 'yepp'
else:
    print 'nope'
```

I keep getting "nope" for this very example. Why?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/11620151/5827958

Comment: `01` is not a double-digit number. It's just `1`. (Actually, it's an octal literal, because of the leading `0`. Python won't even accept something like `08`, because `8` isn't an octal digit. On Python 3, octal literals need to start with `0o`, and Python 3 won't accept `01` at all.)

Comment: @user2357112 So if `08` is the input, how to convert it to 8 (int). Because I can't do any math stuff with a variable like `num = 08`. I get error for `print num*2`.

Comment: Could you state your number as a list of the digits then ints will work

num = [0,1]
if str(num[0])==0:
    print 'yepp'
else:
    print 'nope'

Comment: @fishmong3r: If you're reading numbers from user input, use `int(raw_input())` to read the input, interpret it as the base 10 representation of an integer, and produce the corresponding integer. This integer will not track leading zeros, because leading zeros are not a numeric property; if you want to print it with leading zeros, you can use Python's output formatting tools.

Comment: @user2357112 -- I didn't know that the "010"-meaning-8 had been dropped in Python3, but I heartily approve.  The syntax probably caused me 1 bug for every 4 times I got any value from it, and that is a terrible ratio.

Comment: OP,you can get what  I think you want this way: [`"%02d" % num`](https://pyformat.info/).

Answer (score 1):

`num` is not a string. It is an integer. The integer 1 does not start with `'0'` when converted to a string

Answer (score 0):

The integer value 01 don't exist, it's equal to 1 in Python 2.x and will produce a SyntaxError in Python 3.x.

**Code1:**

```
>>> num = '01'
>>> if str(num).startswith('0'):
>>>     print('yepp')
>>> else:
>>>     print('nope')
yepp
```

**Code2**:

```
>>> num = 01
>>> if str(num).startswith('0'):
>>>     print('yepp')
>>> else:
>>>     print('nope')
File "<ipython-input-4-dafa449070e3>", line 1
  num = 01
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

**Code3:**

```
>>> num = 1
>>> if str(num).startswith('0'):
>>>     print('yepp')
>>> else:
>>>     print('nope')
nope
```