# _tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got "08" (looks like invalid octal number)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am an A-level student writing his coursework for computing. A small part of my codes takes in inputs are turns them into a time. 8 o'clock in the morning is shown like this: 08 ,  Because that's how SQLite likes it. However when converting it into a date I get the error message in the title:

```
_tkinter.TclError: expected floating-point number but got "08" (looks like invalid octal number)
```

This also happens with 09 ,  but not with 06 or 07.

Code:

```
variable_start = IntVar(root)
variable_start.set("Select Start Time")

option_add_start =  ttk.Combobox(window1, textvariable = variable_start,width = 20, state = 'readonly')
option_add_start['values'] = ("06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15",
"16", "17", "18","19", "20")

hour1 = variable_start.get()
min1 = variable_start_min.get()
starttimehour = str(datetime.time(hour1,min1,second))
```

Is it something to do with my datatype? I'm not to sure how to fix it.

Comment: Can you please post your full code, including how you defined the variables `hour1`, `min1` etc.?

Comment: @pkqxdd both hour1 and min1 aren't specifically defined as a certain datatype, so I'm guessing they are characters. My code isn't very tidy, and this is what is causing the problem I think. This is only part of my program, with other modules not affecting this, but if you would like my full code then ill provide a link to it as its very long.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're working in Python 3.x? Python 2 had `0` as a prefix representing octal numbers (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python)), but 3.x does not recognize this form as valid (it instead uses `0o` for octal).

Comment: @Delioth Yes, I am 100% working in python 3, python 3.6.1 to be excact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's your `IntVar`. I don't know if it's a bug or for backwards compatibility, but `IntVar.get()` does type conversion for you. In Python 2, numbers prefixed by `0` would be interpreted in octal (i.e. `010` equals `8`). You're setting the value just fine, but it blows up when it tries to `get()` `"08"`.

Searching through the code, the problem stems from the actual Tcl interpreter, since the `get()` method is sent to the Tcl interpreter as `globalgetvar()`, and from there it's not even interpreted by Python. In reality, it isn't even a bug- Tcl is supposed to recognize `0###` as octal, and this is considered one of the [gotcha's of the language](http://wiki.tcl.tk/498).

The proper workaround for this problem is to use a good data access object- use it to send and retrieve data to and from sqlite. This way you can encapsulate code to transform an integer `8` to the `08` that sqlite wants. The slightly more hacky way is to call a single function before you send data to sqlite, which looks something like:

```
anInt = variable_start.get()
serialInt = serialize(anInt)
send_to_sqlite(serialInt) // I've not worked with SQLite, so this line is pseudocode.

serialize(int):
    new = str(int)
    if(new < 10):
        new = "0" + new
    return new
```

Comment: Thanks you for the explanation, it really helped. I modified some of your code to make it easier to understand for me, but it didn't change the way it worked. I was also getting some errors, so changed the str(int) to 2 different commands, as making it a string before comparing it to an integer didn't work, so I converted it to a string if it met the conditions, by thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
variable_start = IntVar(root)
```

Use:

```
variable_start = StringVar(root)
```

That way there is no problem, because it is clear in advance that it is a string and not an integer.

Then, when you want to use the number data, convert that string to an integer using the standard string to integer conversion function - `int`.

For example:

```
hour1 = int(variable_start.get())
```