# How to make a program start from 0000

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program print all possible 4 digits pin codes.

My program:

```
Pin = 0000
print (Pin)
while Pin < 10000:
    print (Pin)
    Pin = Pin + 1
```

But it start at 0 and then continue 1, 2, 3, 4 and so on.

How do I make it start at 0000 and continue 0001, 0002 - 9998, 9999?

Comment: Take a look at similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134934/display-number-with-leading-zeros

Comment: If you want `02` and `0002` to mean something different, you need to have a different format, e.g. a string `'0002'`, or a tuple `(0, 0, 0, 2)`

Comment: Incidentally, integer literals starting with `0` are interpreted as octal and are only allowed to use digits `0` to `7`. See [What do numbers starting with 0 mean in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to print from 0000 to 9999 try

```
#If not python3 uncomment line below
#from __future__ import print_function
for i in range(10000):
    print("{:04d}".format(i))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the function `zfill()`:

```py
print str(Pin).zfill(4)
```