# Splitting strings of numbers in python

Tags: string, python-2.7, int

When I try to split a string of numbers with '0', it gives me a wrong output.

```
for x in str(0123):
    print x
8
3
```

But if there is no 0, it is correct.

```
for x in str(1234):
    print x
1
2
3
4
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Use `' '` inside `str`.  `for x in str('0123'):`

Comment: As you run this in Python 2 the number 0123 is treated as octal number and resolves to 83 (`eval('0123') == 83`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you put in the number `0123`, it is put in as an integer. Integers have no leading zeros built in, so it reduces itself to `123` before it's converted to the string by the `str()` function.

So your program is seeing `str(123)` instead of `str(0123)`.

You can fix this by making the number a string by use of quotes instead of `str()`:

```
for x in "0123":
    print x
```

Edit: Based on a comment, I realized my explanation had an error. Although the stuff about the integers having no leading zeros built in, there's actually a behavior in Python 2 that does something different.

Integers written with leading zeroes are [octal numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python). So when you put `0123`, `str()` isn't seeing `123` like I said, it's actually seeing `1*8^2+2*8+3 = 83`, and converts `str(83)`, which is the output you are getting.

Regardless, closing the number in quotes still gets you what you want, just for a different reason than I was thinking.