# How to get 09 as an integer in python(odoo)?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests, odoo, odoo-10

I have been trying this code to get the september month as 09 in my code, but later i come to know that 09 is not acceptable in python. But it may displayed as a string only. My question is how to diplay the 09 as an integer?

My code:

```
    september_month = dt.datetime(int(self.year.name),09,30)   
    print september_month
```

Error:
    Invalid token 09 and ValueError: day is out of range for month

This python program runs in odoo version 10 python2.7

Comment: You can't. `09` as an integer is the same as `9` as an integer. If you want to display the leading `0`, format it as a string. Also, in older version of Python, like 2.7, numbers starting with `0` are interpreted as octal, probably leading to much confusion.

Comment: Beware, in python, an integer beginning with a '0' is interpreted as an octal number, thus 09 is invalid and might raise a SyntaxError with invalid token (08 would do the same)

Comment: Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python). Also [this PEP](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/) may be useful

Comment: Why do you need to write the month parameter of `datetime()` with a leading zero? Just wondering.

Answer (score 3):

In Python (in any version), a literal like `09` is interpreted as an octal literal. The value of `9` is therefore invalid.

If you really want to see the `09` you could write a string and convert to integer using `int("09")`. In your code:

```
september_month = dt.datetime(int(self.year.name),int("09"),int("30"))   
print september_month
```

Not sure whether this helps readability, really.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in Python 3 to write `int` values as 01,02,09 etc.

Comment: I asked for python 2.7

Comment: Same answer for python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

Man, it works, your problem is that there is no 31 of september

[image: I tried in the console]

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display the leading 0, format your number as a string:

```
"{:02d}".format(your_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html

Datetime knows what 9 is, no need to put 09

Comment: may be not in 2.7

Comment: @Navi - any evidence for that?  On the contrary, I'm sure that Python 2.7 datetime is the same as 3.x in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
number = 9
formatted_number = str(number).zfill(4)
print(formatted_number)  # Output: '0009'
```