# Unresolved refrence when changing a value on datetime on PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime ,timedelta
import airflow.macros

args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2018, 07, 01),
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=10)
}
```

This shows no errors:

[working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7ttQ.png)

All I do is change the month from `07` to `08` and this generates :

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wi2F.png)

Sorry images are not shown directly.. I have insufficient credit for it so it's shown as link :(

Notice how the `datetime` package becomes "unused"

The errors are:

```
Unresolved refrence datetime
statment expected , found PY:Colon
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 7 and 1 instead of 07 and 01. It will treat the number starting with 0 as octal number in python 2.7. Thats why 08 will be an invalid case in octal. Here is an [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python). In [Python 3.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3127/) it has been changed from 0 to 0o