# Why the result of 41 == 0041 is giving False in python?

Tags: python-2.x

I am trying to retrieve Images in a folder based on indices retrieved from a list. The images format is frame%04d whereas list consists of positive integers. when I passed the following statement 41 == 0041, the result is false. What is the correct procedure?

Comment: You might want to have a look at [What do numbers starting with 0 mean in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python). Literal numbers starting with 0 tell Python that your radix is 8 (octal). So 0041 is really 33 in decimal, and obviously 41 and 33 are not equal.

Comment: That looks like false to me

Comment: In addition to @lurker's comment, `frame41` is a string, as is `frame0041`. The two are not equal, so `false` is the correct result in any language even if there wasn't a special meaning to numbers starting with `0`.

Comment: @lurker Thanks for the clarification issue is resolved

Comment: @lurjer BTW In Python 3, octal literals must begin with `0o`. `041` is an invalid syntax. This question was tagged with Python 3.x, I changed it to Python 2.x

Comment: @DeepSpace ah good catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Python3, it is not even possible to have integer with leading zeros:

```
>>> foo = 0041
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

In Python2, as DeepSpace pointed out, having leading zeros refers to octal literals:

```
>>> 0041
33
>>> 0081
SyntaxError: invalid token
```

Therefore, if you are comparing strings, you can easily do that with

```
>>> "41" == "0041".lstrip("0")
True
```

which results to True

Comment: Not necessarily. `0041` is a valid octal literal in Python 2.