# Can't we assign a value that starts with 0(zero) to a variable ? example: a=0123. This throws error "invalid token"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert that data type to string. Even that's not working.
Example: str(0123)
But this is possible a="0123".
My complete assumption is 0123 is not accepted because it is octal not an integer. So, octal are not allowed in python. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Octal is `0o123`, but `0123` was allowed in Python2 for octal. But this is forbidden in Python3.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `0o123`. Numbers that start with only a zero, which is not the only symbol in the token, are invalid syntax.

Comment: @JohnColeman, that question has the Python-2.7 tag, so I'm not sure how this one is a dupe of that in the first place (although its [original version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26749728/1) is tagged Python 3.x _as well as_ Python 2.7, while using Python 2.7's syntax for `print`). So, my answer about Python 3.x probably wouldn't fit the question about Python 2.7

Comment: Yes it was a bad duplicate target, sorry. I changed it now.

Comment: @ayhan, the OP of that post already knew that "the 0 for octal does not work any more in python (i.e. does not work in _python3_)", and their question was why Python didn't change the meaning of tokens like `001234`, that _don't_ start with `0o` in Python 3.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python) may be a better dupe target. It's still tagged Python 2.7, tough, and it's not really about the difference between Py 2.7 and Py 3.