# Why NumberUtils.isNumber() is not working properly?

Tags: java

when i check with condition 08 or 09 or 010  and above leading with 0  in `org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils.isNumber("08")`

Comment: Hello. Could you [edit] your question and add description of problem you are facing like compilation error, exception stacktrace, expected result vs actual (incorrect?) result? For now it is similar to "I have a problem with my car, when I try to start the engine [and here problem description stops]".

Answer (score 6):

Method isNumber is deprecated:

> isNumber(String str) Deprecated.  This feature will be removed in Lang
>   4.0, use isCreatable(String) instead

Use **isCreatable** for above purpose.

Your above requirement to check ocatl kind of values will be detected via isCreatable method:

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.math.NumberUtils.isCreatable("08") // this will return true.
```

this method Checks whether the String a valid Java number.

> Valid numbers include hexadecimal marked with the 0x or 0X qualifier,
>   octal numbers, scientific notation and numbers marked with a type
>   qualifier (e.g. 123L).
>
> Non-hexadecimal strings beginning with a leading zero are treated as
>   octal values. Thus the string 09 will return false, since 9 is not a
>   valid octal value. However, numbers beginning with 0. are treated as
>   decimal.

reference official [docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isCreatable-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 4):

Non-hexadecimal strings beginning with a leading zero are treated as octal values.

Thus the string **`"09"`** will return **`false`**.

This is because `9` is not a valid octal value.

Reference official [docs](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isNumber-java.lang.String-)

Answer (score 2):

https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isCreatable-java.lang.String-

Use isCreatable instead.  I assume isNumber works basically the same way.

"Non-hexadecimal strings beginning with a leading zero are treated as octal values." Thus the string 09 will return false, since 9 is not a valid octal value. However, numbers beginning with 0. are treated as decimal."

00-07 are numbers. 08--010 are not interpreted as octal numbers, but that is a library issue.

See [What do numbers starting with 0 mean in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python)

When in doubt read the manual.

Comment: "Use isCreatable instead. I assume isNumber works basically the same way." yes, it just calls through

Answer (score 1):

Use isParsable()

```
NumberUtils.isCreatable("09"); // FALSE
NumberUtils.isNumber("09"); // FALSE
NumberUtils.isParsable("09"); // TRUE
```