# Number with 0 in front of it

Tags: python, python-3.x

In normal math notations leading zeros do not matter in the non decimal part.

For ex.

`00003123 = 3123`

`031 + 2 = 33`

However, in python 3, if I try to do a similar operation, I find interesting results that doesn't make sense. **What is happening in Python if the numbers are represented with a/many leading zeros?**

Sample example in python

```
>>> 00003123
1619
>>> 031+2
27
```

Comment: `0` prefix means octal number, and behaviour of those is consistent across Python 2.x and Python 3.x.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do numbers starting with 0 mean in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python)

Comment: You should get a syntax error in Python 3.  The proper octal literal in python 3 would be `0o31`

Comment: "interesting results" should mean it raises a `SyntaxError: invalid token`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literals beginning with zero in python 2 are octal.  For example, octal 31 is 25 in base 10.

For a more complete answer, see [What do numbers starting with 0 mean in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620151/what-do-numbers-starting-with-0-mean-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

```
3 x 512 + 1 x 64 + 2 x 8 + 3 = 1619
3 x 8 + 1 + 2 = 27
```

This is the octal representation, now pretty outdated. Hexadecimal is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

The leading 0 caused Python to interpret the number as an Octal (base 8) so 31 in base 8 is actually 25 in base 10